# How to connect a 4-wire to a 3-wire outlet?

Tags: wiring

My question is about connecting a 4 wire to a 3 wire outlet.  The 4 wire was left sticking out of one corner of the hall closet from a previous wiring job.   Our electrician secured it in a junction box and indicated it can be used to connect a closet light.

Comment: How about a few pictures of the box, switches and the outlet

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved?

Comment: Yes, I'm not clear at all what a "4 wire" is.  It seems like those words are trying to modify a word that is missing, like "chili cheese" needs an extra word like fries, burger, potato, nachos...

Comment: Originally I was thinking range or dryer, but in a closet? Is it Romex red , black, white, ground? Then we would need to know if it was hooked up to a single pole or double pole breaker.

Comment: Was this a laundry closet?  What was connected to the four wire outlet originally?

Comment: probably a 14/3 Romex. it was left laying on hall closet floor, not in junction box. It has a red black white and bare wire. It is hooked up to single pole 15amp breaker. I traced it to a junction box that has a light fixture and GFI outlet. I want to add a light with switch - that has only black white and bare -in the same closet using the red black white bare as source. Is that possible at all and if so what do I do with the red wire?